# Are saved IDLE files saved forever?

Tags: save, python-idle

If you create, save and run a Python IDLE file, is the file saved forever?

Comment: Considering that you saved the file, I'd say yes, the file is saved.......

Comment: If you saved it then it'll be there.

Comment: I would say the simplest answer is: save the file, run it, close the window, and check if the file is there or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run it unless you save it. (By clicking `Save As`) So yes, the file will be saved forever, until you delete it.

Comment: If you want to delete using interpreter:  import os;os.remove(your_file_path_in_quotes)